# Регулярные выражения, китайские иероглифы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Внезапно понадобилось вырезать из текстовых файлов китайские иероглифы и сохранять их в другой файл. Вроде ничего сложного, но я так и не понял как задать диапазон упрощенных иероглифов в регулярном выражении.

Comment: Идея простая - брать по диапазону Unicode. [Пробуйте варианты отсюда](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585914/matching-chinese-characters-with-regular-expressions-php)

Comment: неплохо бы добавить метку языка, в котором вы используете регулярные выражения

Comment: PHP: `preg_replace_callback('~\p{Han}+~', function($m) use($filename) { savetofile($m[0], $filename); return ''; }, $str);`